# Android won't create second instance of activity

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm calling startActivity from a method in my Application class, but neither the activity's constructor nor its onCreate method is being called.  The Application method is being called when a menu option (in the first activity instance) is selected, so the first activity is on top.  I don't have a launchMode set for the activity (i.e. it is "standard"), and onNewIntent is not being called.

However, if I copy the .java file (+ rename the class and copy the Activity entry in AndroidManifest.xml), then call startActivity with the new class the second time, it works just fine.  I need to create an unknown and possibly high number of these activities, so this is not a solution, especially when you consider all the duplicated code.

How can I force Android to create multiple instances of this activity?

Comment: As far as I am aware, activities aren't meant to be used like this. I feel that some example code/further explanation is required in order for us to see what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Have you tried adding the addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); and then calling the activity ??

Comment: Unfortunately this is for a closed source commercial product, so I can't release any source code.  I am happy to clarify anything that might be helpful, though.

Comment: Girish, I just tried that, and it brought up the new activity, but as the documentation mentions it also destroyed the old activity.  I need to keep both alive.

Comment: I have a hard time believing this. The default behaviour is that if ActivityA calls `startActivity()` for ActivityA that a new instance of ActivityA gets created. I've got simple test programs that do exactly this. You must be doing something funky. Are you sure you haven't specified any Intent flags or launchMode or activity flags in the manifest that would change this standard behaviour?